# gradle cannto find subproject of dependency

Tags: gradle

I have the following structure:

```
./mainproject/
    -settings.gradle
    -build.gradle
    -subproject/
        -build.gradle
        -/src/...
./libraryproject
    -settings.gradle
    -build.gradle
    -subproject_interfaces/
        -build.gradle
        -src/...
    -subproject_impl/
        -build.gradle
        -src/...
```

libraryproject/settings.gralde:

```
rootProject.name = 'library'
include 'subproject_interfaces','subproject_impl'
```

libraryproject/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':subproject_interfaces')
    compile project(':subprojects_impl')
}
```

mainproject/settings.gradle

```
include "library"
project(':library').projectDir = new File(settingsDir,"../libraryproject")
```

mainproject/subproject/build.gradle

```
dependencies{
    compile project(':library')
}
```

- I can gradle build libraryproject fine.
- I can gradle build libraryproject via the project dependency on mainproject fine.
- I **cannot** build mainproject due to:  `Project with path: 'subproject_interfaces' could not be found in project ' library'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the multi-project feature.
In one multi-project build you have exactly **one** `settings.gradle` and there you have to build the whole project tree.
You cannot delegate from the main build `settings.gradle` to the library build `settings.gradle`.
If you want to work like that, you also have to include the subprojects of the library project in the `settings.gradle` of the main build.
Alternatively, you can depend on the library by means of coordinates and deploy the library to some repository like `mavenLocal()`, but of course then the library project is not automatically rebuilt if you build the main project, but you have to manually (vai gradle task) deploy the library artifacts.

Alternatively you can also call the library build with a task of type GradleBuild and then depend on the output of that build. Then the library build remains a complete own Gradle build that is just triggered by your main build.